# How to iterate dynamically over a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dynamic

How to iterate over a dictionary / JSON using a dynamic query.

For example consider the below dict

```
dict = {'Adam': {
            'English': {
                'Score': 99,
                'Time': 3400,
                'Classes': 4},
            'Math': {
                'Score': 45,
                'Time': 779,
                'Classes': 5}},
        'Tim': {
            'English': {
                'Score': 74,
                'Time': 12,
                'Classes': 99},
            'Math': {
                'Score': 12,
                'Time': 333,
                'Classes': 1}}
        }
```

I want to set the value of a given path for example

```
path = '/Adam/English/Score'
new_value = 87
```

Note that the value assigned could be another dict as well for example

```
path = '/Adam/English'
new_value = {'Score': 11,
             'Time': 2,
             'Classes': 9}
```

Any help would be useful.

Edit: Below is my attempt

```
keys = path.split('/')[1:]
new_data = None
for key in keys:
    if new_data is None:
        new_data = dict[key]
    else:
        new_data = new_data[key]

new_data = new_value
print(dict)
```

But here the `dict` still has the old value

Comment: @timgeb, You see it's not about assigning values to dictionaries, I am unsure when the path that I need to assign the value to can be dynamic, i.e when the structure of the dictionary is unknown. 

Unfortunately I am not aware of any pointers in Python that could have solved my problem by iterating over the query path.

Comment: Split the path into parts, then iterate over the parts with a `for` loop. Again you'd get much better help if you had an attempt we could then fix.

Comment: Thank you. Add that to the question itself and include the error you are getting and I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some assumptions, for example that `'/'` is not part of any dict-keys and that the path must be valid. Adjust the function as needed.

```
def deep_set(d, path, value):
    sep = '/'
    *trail, last = path.strip(sep).split(sep)
    
    for part in trail:
        d = d[part]
        
    d[last] = value
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> deep_set(d, 'a', 2)
>>> d
{'a': 2}
>>> d = {'a': {'b': 1}}
>>> deep_set(d, 'a/b', 2)
>>> d
{'a': {'b': 2}}
```

edit:

Note that if there are consecutive `'/'` characters then the empty string will be looked up as a dict key. e.g.

`'a/b//c'.split('/') -> ['a', 'b', '', 'c']`

It's unclear whether you want to treat leading/trailling `'/'` characters as part of the path or not (in my function, they are removed with `str.strip`). Again, adjust as needed.

Comment: Got it. I've made the few errors handling that you mentioned in the case the key does not exist. Much appreciated.